# Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 crash when try to debug memory dump

Tags: dump, postsharp

Whenever I try to debug memory dump my VS 2015 crashes. I tried to disable extensions one by one and found that PostSharp Tools For Visual Studio 2015 v. 4.3.17 causes the crash.

Does anybody experiencing the same issue?

Comment: Could you please open Event Viewer, look for the crash record for the process devenv.exe, and report it here? Thans.

Comment: What if the answer is "yes"? Please ask questions that are helpful.